# Adding a cookie to a HTTP request

Tags: java, php, android, cookies

I'm trying to add a cookie with a GUID to identify the user but my code doesn't seem to send any cookies when I run it on my test script.

My Java code:

```
    public void search(String q, int o) {
    final String query = q;
    final int offset = o;
    Thread searchThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                BasicHttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
                httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
                cookieStore.addCookie(new BasicClientCookie("remixsid", guid));
                httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.43/test/test.php?section=audio&q=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, HTTP.UTF_8) + "&offset=" + offset);
                //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://vkontakte.ru/gsearch.php?section=audio&q=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, HTTP.UTF_8) + "&offset=" + offset);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                System.out.print(responseBody);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    };
    searchThread.run();
}
```

My PHP code to test for cookies:

```
<?php
$cookies = $_COOKIE;

if(!count($cookies) > 0)
    echo 'No cookies!';

foreach ($cookies as $key=>$val)
    echo "$key--> $val";

?>
```

The GUID is retrieved with this code:

```
    public void login(String usr, String pass) {
    logout();
    final String username = usr;
    final String password = pass;
    Thread loginThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://login.vk.com/?act=login&email=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, HTTP.UTF_8) + "&pass=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, HTTP.UTF_8));
                httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
                for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                    System.out.println("Cookie: " + cookie.toString());
                    if(cookie.getName().contains("remixsid"))
                        guid = cookie.getValue();
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                System.out.println("An error occured");
                if(loginHandler != null)
                    loginHandler.onLoginError(e);
                return;
            }
            if(!isLoggedIn()) {
                System.out.println("User credentials invalid");
                if(loginHandler != null)
                    loginHandler.onLoginInvalidCredentials();
                return;
            }
            if(loginHandler != null)
                loginHandler.onLoginSuccess();
            System.out.println("Login successfull GUID is: " + guid);
        }
    };
    loginThread.start();
}
```

Comment: please try log before call HttpPost request.

Comment: @Nik.... No Exceptions are occurring in the script. All I'm getting is the response: "No cookies".

Comment: For a more generic way to add cookies to your HTTP request [Check my answer here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393252/android-http-cookie-help/13333562#13333562

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting the cookie header manually seems to work...

```
    public void search(String q, int o) {
    final String query = q;
    final int offset = o;
    Thread searchThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.43/test/test.php");
                //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://vkontakte.ru/gsearch.php?section=audio&q=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, HTTP.UTF_8) + "&offset=" + offset);
                httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", "remixsid=" + guid);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                System.out.println(responseBody);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    };
    searchThread.start();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, and I had to do ".addHeader(...)" because I was manually adding a handful of headers to my POST, not just one. (I believe that's the difference between setHeader and addHeader.)

Answer (score 2):

Few comments and suggestions:

1. You are not adding any **path info** to the cookie. You can use `BasicClientCookie.setPath()` method.
2. What is the **path of the php** script which is trying to read this cookie?
3. When a cookie set at **root path** (`/`), then only it becomes available to *all* other server side programs.
4. Either set the path of the cookie to root or make the path of the cookie same as the path the PHP script.

EDIT:

I missed the domain part. You also need to set the cookie domain. Assuming that your PHP script runs at `http://mysite/myscript.php` Here `mysite` is the domain (it could be `localhost` if your are running the script at your local box). Use `BasicClientCookie.setDomain()` to set the cookie domain.

To understand this, assume your http-client lib as browser interacting with a web site. The browser stores cookies from many sites, but while making a request to a particular site  it sends only those cookies which it has received from that particular site.

If the domain is not set, the lib wont send the cookie to that host.

Comment: I've tried this:

BasicClientCookie loginCookie = new BasicClientCookie("remixsid", guid);
loginCookie.setPath("/");
cookieStore.addCookie(loginCookie);

But it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check.

Comment: @JonKoops, I know I'm a bit late but you also have to set the cookie's domain `loginCookie.setDomain("mydomain.com")`